# Another way to display content from external file in html

Tags: javascript, html, file, load, external

I have a html file with a UL element.
I want to load the LI elements for this UL from an external file that will be in the same folder as the html file.
The external file can be any type of file. So .html or .txt, xml maybe? (preferably not JS)

Methods i've tried that work but why I don't want to use them:

**jQuery load** Works ofcourse but I don't want to use external libraries for a relatively easy request.

**XMLhttprequest** It's going to be a local very simple tool for co-workers, and this also seems too big of a request for just 10 li's.

**w3 Include** Same as XMLHTTPrequest

**document.write** I'm using document.write right now as a solution, but then the external file is a .js file. I rather have my coworkers work in a HTML or txt file plus i read a lot of negative stuff about document.write. And this file starts with: document.write(' - and i rather have the file start with the li's like  < li > 1 < / li >

**iframe or object** I don't like how these tags append a whole new html and body tag to the UL and also styling is an issue.

**php** also to big of a step for just a local web application.

**File reader** also tried letting the user upload a txt file in a filereader. But I don't want the upload option

I probably tried more than the above solutions. But I just can't wrap my head around that this can't be done more easily or lightweight if the file is in the same folder.

Looking for a simple / easy solution if possible.

Comment: "*if the file is in the same folder.*" webapps don't really care where files are *on the disk*. Any requests are for resources that might or might not even exist on the same machine. In HTTP context, it's not "in the same folder". Hence, it's not easy.

Comment: `fetch` the local file and then set the HTML of your UL element with `element.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Native implementation of HTML Imports will be removed from Chrome 73 so it is now recommended to use native fetch(), or third-party libraries.

**DEPRECATED**
look at https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/

```
<link rel="import" href="myfile.html">
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I thought this was deprecated? Tried this too, but didn't work and found out it was deprecated

Comment: edit the comment sorry - dont use this function so far :D